# Am i suppose to write/read file during kernel module init/exit?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I want to saving my kernel module variable when unloading the module, then read the saved data when the module loading next time.

What I am thinking is that reading the variable when calling module_init(), and saving the variable when calling module_exit().

I didn't try anything cause I have seen lots of article said that reading/writing a file in kernel mode is not prefered.

So how do I suppose to solve the problem?